# How, in Matlab, can i traverse a tree and save node numbers in a separate matrix in required order?

Tags: matlab, networking

[image]
I am using Matlab to implement my project. Please help me with the following.

In Matrix A (Figure above), elements of any particular row represent the nodes that are within the communication range of the node represented by the row number. For example node 2 and 12 are with in node 1's communication range, 3 and 13 are within 2's range, 4 is in node 12's range and so on. The tree(or network) in the picture is drawn using matrix A.

I want matrix M for each node x where the first row of M contains the nodes that are within the range of node x(lets call this set of node S1), the second row of M should contain all those nodes that are within the range of any of the nodes in S1(lets call this set S2), the third row should contain all the nodes that are within the range of the nodes in S2 and so on. Right side of the image shows some examples of the required matrices. Both the input and output matrices are size nxn and contain 0's to represent null(For simplicity, I removed unnecessary rows and columns i.e those with all zero's).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
% Define tree
A1 = [2 12 0; 3 13 0; 0 0 0; 6 8 0; 10 9 11; 5 7 0];
A2 = zeros([7 3]);
A2(6, 1) = 4;
A = cat(1, A1, A2);

% Initialize loop
[nNodes, nConn] = size(A);
out = cell([1 nNodes]);

% Loop over number of nodes
for iNode = 1 : nNodes

    % Get children
    thisOut = A(iNode,:);

    % Go to next iteration if terminal node
    if ~any(thisOut)
        continue
    end

    % Iterate over levels of nodes (distances from node)
    iLevel = 1;
    while true

        % Get children
        children = thisOut(iLevel,:);
        children = children(children ~= 0);

        % Get the connections of the children
        nextLevel = A(children,:);

        % Break if terminal node reached
        if ~any(nextLevel(:))
            break;
        end

        % Process connections of the children
        nextLevel = nextLevel(nextLevel~=0);
        if numel(nextLevel) < nConn
            nextLevel = cat(1, nextLevel(:), zeros([nConn-numel(nextLevel),1]));
        end

        % Attach the result of the current level
        thisOut = cat(1, thisOut, nextLevel');
        iLevel = iLevel+1;
    end

    % Write to output cell array
    out{iNode} = thisOut;
end
```